# phonegap / cordova database

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, cordova-3

I'm working with database in cordova.i have successfully insert into the database.
 as well as fetch data from the database.
but now, the problem is while insert the data at first time.its perfectly inserted.but when i insert second data into database,than the second data is override on first data.
this is the code::

```
$(document).on('click','#btnSubmit',function(){
  var db = window.openDatabase("demo", "1.0", "demo DB", 1000000);
  db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
});

// Populate the database function populateDB(tx) {
var id = 1;
alert(":id:"+id);
var Title = document.getElementById("Title").value;
var Location = document.getElementById("Location").value;
var Notes = document.getElementById("Notes").value;
var StartDate = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
var EndDate = document.getElementById("EndDate").value;

tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Event');
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Event (id unique, Title,Location,Notes,StartDate,EndDate)');
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Event(Title,Location,Notes,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES ('"+Title+"','"+Location+"','"+Notes+"','"+StartDate+"','"+EndDate+"')"); }

// Transaction error callback
function errorCB(tx, err) {  
  alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}

// Transaction success callback
function successCB() {
  $.mobile.changePage( "ListEvent.html", { transition: "flip"} );
}
```

Comment: its not getting overridden your dropping the table everytime before insert

Comment: how can i check that table is exist or not?

Comment: You have already written the code for that Create table... comment your delete code